# Maven verify for Sonar fails on svn: E175002

Tags: maven, ssl, svn, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Freshly installed SonarQube 6. Fresh checkout of SVN repository using

```
sudo svn https://mySvnServer --username myUsername
```

Accepting certificate of the `mySvnServer` permanently. SonarQube server is started and I prepare for a maven verify as per [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).

```
sudo mvn clean verify sonar:sonar
```

Almost after 99% of the process, it fails with the following error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.
0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project com.foo.bar: Error when executing blame for fil
e src/main/java/com/foo/bar/MyJavaClass.java: svn: E175002: Connection has been sh
utdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
[ERROR] svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/full-SVN-Path-To-My-Project/
MyJavaClass.java'
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch
.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solut
ions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVE
N/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :clear.ng
```

Tried reading through lot related problems posted, and managed to get a somewhat knowledge of the problem, but clueless about where and what changes would solve the same.

Comment: Your Subversion server version is quite old, right?

Comment: @bahrep Visual SVN Server version 1.8.9. Is it too old for this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your VisualSVN Server instance. VisualSVN Server 2.7 is no longer supported and does not receive security or bug fixes anymore. The current VisualSVN Server release version is **3.5.x**.

For immediate fix, apply the last patch update: [VisualSVN Server 2.7.14](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/2.7/).

A patch update is a minor update within the same release version. Applying a minor patch update is always painless and fast; patch updates contain only bug fixes and no new features. With version 2.7.14 you should not get such errors anymore because we applied a workaround in [version 2.7.9](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v2.7.9):

> Disable SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to workaround
>   non-compliant Subversion clients that incorrectly handle SSL handshake
>   alerts.

The problem is that non-compliant Subversion clients may handle SSL handshake alerts incorrectly. In your particular case, I guess that there is different server name that is used in the certificate, in the URL and in server's settings hence there is a handshake warning the client is unable to process properly. Such alerts have to be considered as mere warnings but older and some Java-based clients treat them as critical errors resulting in one of the errors mentioned above.

BTW, it's a good idea to install a valid and properly signed certificate to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. I wanted, Sonar not to probe into SVN repository and only scan code. So I disabled the SVN scanner. It is done by following setting at Sonar Server and it worked.

```
At Administration -> Configuration -> SCM, check "Disable the SCM Scanner"
```